# Force the height in css

Tags: html, css

I have a problem, in fact I have a block named "e-mail" which descend, I will want to force the height, is it possible?

Do you have an idea of the process to follow?

I don't know if my pratice html/css is good also?

Thank you for your answer.

```css
.logo5{
  padding-top: 35px;
  padding-left: 80px;
}

.title-contact-1{
  font-family: 'Questrial', sans-serif;
  font-size: 22px;
  margin-top: -32px;
  padding-left: 100px;
  position: absolute;
}

.text-contact-1{
  padding-left: 80px;
}

.line-verticale{
  margin-top: -60px;
  margin-left: 250px;
  border-left:1px solid #e0e0e0;
  height:100px;
}

.logo6{
  padding-top: 35px;
  padding-left: 80px;
}

.title-contact-2{
  font-family: 'Questrial', sans-serif;
  font-size: 22px;
  margin-top: -32px;
  padding-left: 120px;
  position: absolute;
}

.text-contact-2{
  padding-left: 80px;
}
```

```html
<div class="background-contact">
   <img class="logo5" src="https://i.ibb.co/0YyTszS/title-icon1.png">
   <div class="title-contact-1">Telephone</div>
   <div class="text-contact-1">Just For VIP Member</div>
   <div class="line-verticale" ></div>
   <img class="logo6" src="https://i.ibb.co/026Fs1B/title-icon2.png">
   <div class="title-contact-2">E-mail</div>
   <div class="text-contact-2">admin@superbtc.biz</div>
   <div class="line-verticale" ></div>
</div>
```

Comment: What's the problem with the `height` css property?

Answer (score 0):

I think the email descends because of the image size. Have you tried setting image size? The telephone image and email is of different size. For example,

```
img {
max-width: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to restructure, but now you can adjust images and the content easily

```css
.contact-info {
    font-family: 'Questrial', sans-serif;
}

.contact-item {
    border-right: 1px solid #e0e0e0;
    padding: 20px;
    max-width: 200px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    text-align: center;
}

.contact-item__logo {
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.contact-item__title {
    font-size: 22px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.contact-item--email .contact-item__title {
    padding-top: 10px
}

.contact-item__text {
    margin-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="contact-info background-contact">
    <div class="contact-item contact-item--phone">
        <div class="contact-item__header">
            <img class="contact-item__logo" src="https://i.ibb.co/0YyTszS/title-icon1.png">
            <span class="contact-item__title">Telephone</span>
        </div>
        <div class="contact-item__text">Just For VIP Member</div>
    </div>
    <div class="contact-item contact-item--email">
        <div class="contact-item__header">
            <img class="contact-item__logo" src="https://i.ibb.co/026Fs1B/title-icon2.png">
            <span class="contact-item__title">E-mail</span>
        </div>
        <div class="contact-item__text">admin@superbtc.biz</div>
    </div>
</div>
```